# Doctrine Query Builder: Joining same entity class in multiple fields

Tags: doctrine, many-to-many, dql

I have an entity called `Path`, which is linked to another entity `Product` using two different fields.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Path
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product")
     */
    private $products;
}
```

Links in different fields are done due to the need to perform some logic on "main" product, while allowing attaching to multiple products in some other parts of the app.

EDIT: Product in `product` field is not present in `products` field.

I'm looking to build a query that will do some other checks against `Product`, possibly joining with other entities related to `Product`. I'd like database to perform only one join with product table (as I would if it weren't done in Doctrine).

Currently I've got a `QueryBuilder` set up like so:

```
$qb->leftJoin("path.products", 'path_product');
$qb->join(Product::class, 'products', 'WITH', "path.product = products OR path_product.id = products.id")
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT path.id AS id_0
  FROM path path 
  LEFT JOIN path_product path_product ON path.id = path_product.path_id
  LEFT JOIN product product_1 ON product_1.id = path_product.product_id
  LEFT JOIN product product_2 ON (path.product_id = product_2.id OR product_1.id = product_2.id)
```

(It's a simplified SQL generated from Doctrine Query Builder with unnecessary fields removed and expanded aliases)

...but this generates one additional join with `Product`'s table, which feels "dirty". Is there some other way to do a join like this?